# Android - How to reduce hoverable bounds of a ClipDrawable?

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-shape

I currently have the following XML for my ClipDrawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<clip
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:clipOrientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="top">

    <shape
        android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="#ff0000"/>
        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="#000"/>
        <size
            android:width="80dp"
            android:height="80dp"/>
    </shape>
</clip>
```

To clip off the bottom portion, I have this line of code:

```
circle1.getBackground().setLevel(3100);
```

However, even after I clip off the bottom portion, the portion that is clipped off remains hoverable.  I would like to know, how would I change the bounds of `circle1` to make the clipped portion non-hoverable?

BTW, this app is using a mouse via USB OTG, with `onHover` being used to handle hover events.